# Using Boost with Xcode4

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, xcode4

has anyone setup a C++ Xcode4 project to use Boost? what settings do I need to set in Xcode for a simple C++ console application?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Managed it with this:

[image: Link binaries with libraries]

and this:

[image]

Comment: where did u get the libboost_system.dylib ? I need system and thread. can you share it please? or share with us how you get it?

Comment: It was copied over as part of the install process I followed here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

Comment: I got an error saying "image not found". What resolved this, was that I added the necessary files to the output by selecting "Targets" and then "Build Phases". Then, under "Copy Files", I added "libboost_filesystem.dylib" and "libboost_system.dylib" to the "Products Directory" (select from "Destination" dropdown). No subfolder needed

Answer (score 6):

I would just like to add on to the previous post:

After running

$ sudo port install boost (this can be done once you have macports installed).

libboost_system.dylib and libboost_filesystem.dylib could be found in /opt/local/lib/

boost_1_46_1.tar.bz2 will be located in /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/boost/
Unarchive it, then copy and paste the folder named "Boost" to /usr/local/include/

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the boost libraries for unix from : http://www.boost.org/
2. Unzip it : Let's say now you have boost in "($USER_NAME)/boost_X_YY_0"
3. Open your console Application project
4. Click on top left node in the project directory pane (left hand side). This should be your project name
5. Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths ->Add the "($USER_NAME)/boost_X_YY_0" path
6. #include "boost/any.hpp" will work